# How to print 1 in every thousand frames using opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to save one frame in every thousand frames of a video. Below is the code I am currently using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/Surgery1.mpg')
try:
    if not os.path.exists('D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/data_surg1'):
    os.makedirs('D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/data_surg1')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data_surg1')
currentFrame = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    if currentFrame > 0:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,currentFrame) 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
    name = 'D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/data_surg1/frame' + str(currentFrame/1000) + '.jpg'
    print ('Creating...' + name)
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    # To stop duplicate images
    currentFrame += 1000

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I am not sure if this is saving it correctly. When I look at the frames in the file explorer, the numbers are initially very high and then reduce to form a sequential frame number compared to the previous image. I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV3.3.

Comment: Can you show us what the names of your files are coming out as?

Comment: Why are you setting the position in milliseconds when you want to filter by frame number? While that may work in case the frame rate of the video file is 1000 FPS, even then that's a rather obscure way of expressing your intent.

Comment: try cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES instead of msec

Comment: Thanks @Micka The output I get when I use the cv2.CAP_PROP_PROP_POS_FRAMES as opposed to MSEC gives me exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing from certain frames instead of a time-based save, the following script works:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/Surgery1.mpg')
try:
    if not os.path.exists('D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/data_surg1'):
    os.makedirs('D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/data_surg1')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data_surg1')
currentFrame = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    if currentFrame > 0:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,currentFrame) 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
    name = 'D:/01 Projects/AMAZON CATALYST PROJECT/data_surg1/frame' + str(currentFrame/1000) + '.jpg'
    print ('Creating...' + name)
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    # To stop duplicate images
    currentFrame += 1

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```